# How to scroll custom list view in Alert Dialog programmatically?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm developing an Android app. Currently I've implemented custom list view in Alert Dialog. This is the code so far:

```
private void setupAlertDialogBuilder(final Context context) {
        GiftStoreCountriesAdapter giftStoreCountriesAdapter = new GiftStoreCountriesAdapter(context,
                R.layout.gift_store_countries_row,
                giftStoreCountriesViewModel.fetchCountriesFromLocalDatabase(),
                (HomeActivity) context);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_currency_icon)
                .setAdapter(giftStoreCountriesAdapter, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handleCountrySelection(dialog, which);
            }
        });
        builder.create().getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        builder.create().getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(scrollToPosition(context));
    }
```

Everything works fine except one thing. How can I programmatically scroll that custom list view to the some position or index of row as soon as alert dialog is shown to user. I've tried with this:

```
builder.create().getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);  
    builder.create().getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(scrollToPosition(context));
```

but it doesn't work. If I put just:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(scrollToPosition(context));
```

without `builder.create()` I get `NullPointerException`. This is in class that is custom Alert Dialog and it `extends AlertDialog`. I need to automatically scroll this list when it's shown to user. I appreciate all your help.